# HP Proliant N36L: Boot from internal USB with other USB-drives attached

Tags: boot, usb, hp-proliant

I want to boot from the internal USB drive.

But when I attach external USB drives, the system tries to boot from these instead.

Answer (score 1):

- Attach all USB-devices.
- Boot.
- Hold F10 to go into BIOS.
- Go to 'Boot'.
- Go to 'Hard disk drives'
- Disable all drives except 'USB: General Flash'
- Change Boot Priority: Select 'USB: General Flash'.
- Save.

The tricky part is that you have to have all USB-drives attached before you can disable the drives. And only after you have disabled them, can you select the correct USB-device as boot device.